# How to display thread in 100 lines, each line length of 100 characters

Tags: java, multithreading

How to display thread in 100 lines, each line length of 100 characters ?

```
    public class CustomThread extends Thread{

    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    CustomThread( String threadName){
        this.threadName = threadName;
        System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                    System.out.println(threadName);
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }

    public void start ()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
        if (t == null)
        {
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start ();
        }
    }
}
```

How to display 100 lines, when each line length of 100 characters.

My main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CustomThread T1 = new CustomThread("1");
        T1.start();

       }
}
```

This character is "1". But how to display 100 lines on 100 characters, that thread ? My code is not work.

Comment: why don't you name your thread?

Comment: Off-topic but: why does your class `extends Thread` instead of `implement Runnable`?

Comment: How are you creating these threads? You already have a constructor that accepts a name?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that your code doesn't work? What's the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just name your own thread?

```
    Thread.currentThread().setName("Bob");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Anyway, to print your rows, change

```
System.out.println(threadName);
```

to

```
System.out.print(threadName);
```

`println()` always include a new line character

Comment: sorry, i edit my question. thanks for you answer.

Comment: @PidunaV.A. and I edited my answer. You should have posted a whole new question, anyway.